# "No Network Access" on old domestic network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I'm having problems connecting my laptop to the Wi-Fi network at my parent's home. It worked last year, and the only change I can think of is having installed **Windows 10**. If I tether the laptop to my smartphone and the smartphone to the same network the connection works.

- The network status from the network and sharing center lists IPv4
  connectivity as "no network access".
- I checked the router settings and I didn't find MAC address
  restrictions.
- The DNS address is 192.168.0.1, but I also tried the Google ones.
- The DHCP client in services is set on automatic.
- The network is listed as 'public network'.
- Pinging 4.2.2.2 results in time outs
- I tried deleting the connection and reconnecting (I was re-asked for
  password, but not for privacy level)

Comment: 1) `the only change I can think of is having installed Window 10` and thus complete changed everything on the laptop. That is a non-trivial change!
2) There really is not enough information to even make a decent guess in your post. No mention if the cable is properly plugged in, if drivers for the NIC are recignised, if you get link....

Comment: At the time when the question was asked the OS upgrade had preserved all settings, the computer could connect normally to other networks. About the cable, the question mentions this is related to wi-fi.

Comment: Also, having since re-installed the OS , incidentally solving the problem, I can't offer any further information.

Comment: @Hennes what kind of additional information do you think would have been useful to identify the problem presented in the question?

Comment: Did the cable provide link (read plugged in properly). Did ipt get information from DHCP? If it did, did that contain IP addresss, network mask, default gateway and DNS servers? Could yo ping the gateway (if not, give iup on DNS testing, solve the lower level prblem first), ....

Comment: The cable was plugged enough for other devices to work, I didn't do further testing from console, I stopped at checking the settings from the Windows GUI. Regrettably I already re-installed the system because of other issues.